# Flight controller board Reprogram

Tags: i2c, stm32, drone

Recently in my scrap yard visits, more and more I find cheap quad-copters and remote controllers of all kind. I have built up quite a collection of boards and spare parts to create my own army of drones.
Now, my question is, how can I access the microprocessor on the board to upload code, say MultiWii, Ardupilot or similar.
I know every board is different, but very often I see STM32 processors on these boards, with I2c connections available.
Should there be also TX and Rx pins for USB communication in order to flash the controller? Or can it be done with I2c and an arduino as a master?

Comment: Have you googled on how to program a standalone STM32? Tx and Rx are commonly for UART interfaces and has nothing to do with USB. For programming over serial you need a bootloader on the chip

Comment: Well, of course one does his fair bit of research before asking a question...

Comment: Have you seen [this guide](https://stm32-base.org/guides/connecting-your-debugger). It explains how to flash an STM32 via the SWD/JTAG interface. You need an SWD/JTAG debugger to do this. Does that help?

Comment: No, that is one of the many things I have probably missed, it explains exactly what to do. Thank you.